# How to replace src in angular before browser call for that image?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-directive

I want to replace `src` of the image based on few scenario and I want to handle it through angular directive so that I don't need to find out all the image tag and write code for each. I'm trying to achieve this by writing a directive wrapper to image tag so that I can handle there.

I'm facing few issues with `iso-lated scope` in my directive. See [here (JSFiddle)](http://jsfiddle.net/Lvc0u55v/7215/)

1. Can you please help me to replace image `src`?
2. I also want to make sure that when we replace the `src` there should be only one call in network tab for fetching image.

Comment: Can you provide more information about your requirment. I am able to get image by replacing ng-src with src only as you are binding @src in directive scope, look here http://jsfiddle.net/9r4eutLy/2/. For second point you can store array of binary64 string of image and use it as cache. You need to write img tag with binary64 string value...

Comment: I want to change the src. Right now the image which you got is the one I've set in controller. Can you please change src through directive (That is my requirement) and make sure that when you change src, I don't want request for google-logo.jpg.

Comment: not sure, is this what you are looking for - http://jsfiddle.net/rcv0ja3b/2/

Comment: @Developer Can you help me to get the same output without changing name of the directive. I want to extend <img> tag features so...

Comment: finally what the directive renders is plane <img> itself...will that help? or you can make changes in the directive template - template: '<img ng-src="{{imgSrc}}"/>'

Comment: or check this out - http://jsfiddle.net/rcv0ja3b/3/